# Max fields in ADO recordset

Tags: excel, vba, field, ado, recordset

I am trying to make a secured database in access and a userform in excel. I understand all the VBA and most of the syntax for sending and receiving data from access to excel. My issue is that i can only write to 64 fields (0-63) I have over 75 columns I want to move back and forth between access and excel. Here is some of my code it that is not clear.

```
' open the database based on type of save
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        ' open the recordset
'.MaxRecords = 70
.Open "SELECT * FROM " & TableName & " WHERE [Task_Number] = '" & MyCriteria & "'", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
countfields = .Fields.Count 'Returns 132
.Fields(60).Value = "60" 'Works
.Fields(61).Value = "61" 'Works
.Fields(62).Value = "62" 'Works
.Fields(63).Value = "63" 'Works
.Fields(64).Value = "64" 'Does not work
.Fields(65).Value = "65" 'Does not work
.Fields(66).Value = "66" 'Does not work
.Fields(80).Value = "80" 'Does not work
.Update ' stores the new record
            End With
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        cn.Close

        Set cn = Nothing
```

the .MaxRecords is set to 0 (unlimited) but i have also tried to change it to the number of records i need and to how many fields i have in my recordset.

Comment: It is hard to say a database is secured if you are making a userform in Excel that is going to store a connection to that DB.

Comment: Please confirm what error you are getting. ie What does "Does not work" mean.

Comment: What do you get if you do rs.fields.Count?

Comment: Please try the code in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this into your code after

```
countfields = .Fields.Count 'Returns 132
```

and see what happens

```
Dim intLoop  as long 

    For intLoop = 0 To (.fields.Count - 1)
        With rs.fields.Item(intLoop) 
            Debug.Print .Name, .value, .type, .DefinedSize 
        End With 
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies but I was able to figure out why I was having issues. I am new to access and when I built the table the first 64 columns were formatted to text, but when I added more columns they were formatted as dates... therefore when I was trying to put text or number into the field it would just drop out and act like it was not able to access it. HarveyFrench your response would of helped me figure this out, I wish I would asked the question sooner...

Thanks again! and I hope this helps the next person with similar issues.